# Confusion in transistor circuit

Tags: transistors, automotive

I'm hacking my car's locking system, I want to be able to lock/unlock using a MC and ultimately my phone. I've spliced the connector and after a quick inspection I located the 3 pins that do just that, I've labeled them lock, unlock and common. As you probably guessed shorting lock and common locks the car and shorting unlock and common unlocks it. I wish I could go with a simple schematic like this:

[image]

The problem is that I measure 12V across Unlock and COM, but it goes the opposite way -3V across Lock and COM, so the schematic turns into this:

[image]

Which can't work because COM and Lock are permanently shorted. I thought of adding a third transistor on the red lock path but I'm losing the feeling of knowing what I'm doing at this point.

The next obvious solution is to use relays but I'd like to ask if there's a smarter solution to this problem?

Note: I'm using TIP120s because I have a handful laying around, I'm aware it's probably overkill and also I'm just a hobbyist, please don't give me a hard time if that stuff is too basic.

### Update:

As suggested in the comments I measured the voltages of all pins relative to ground and here are the results:

Unlock: 12.6V
COM: 1.09V
Lock: 0.00V

I also measured the resistance of Lock to ground which turned out to be 30.8 Ohms if that is relevant in any way.

Comment: measure all three, lock, unlock, and common to ground.  - I'm getting a feeling that it may be possible to control the locks by changing the voltage on the common terminal.

Comment: What make, model, and year of vehicle is is? You may be able to find a proper wiring diagram for free: https://www.autozone.com/repairguides/

Comment: @VE7JRO I believe it's an aftermarket installation, even if it were standard chances are I'd be unable to read the diagram.

Comment: @Jasen I'm currently away but after the weekend I'll be able to provide more info, thank you for the advice.

Comment: @Jasen I added the info, I'm a little confused to say the least.

Comment: Given that you don't know what kind of circuitry you are dealing with in the car, the smartest solution probably is to use relays, in fact. Even if you could figure out a way to do it with transistors, you wouldn't know how to properly protect the transistors against reverse voltage, spikes and other mishaps. I'd rather go the easy route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the voltage measurements it seems likely that unlock is actually a connection to the battery (via a fuse) and lock is a ground connection. making common the input to the central locking controller.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9AlLi.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have placed R4 and R5 here to prevent smoke when someone presses the opposite control to what the arduino wants. as this is an automotive circuit I have chosen transistors that can withstand 100V or more.

Q2 emitter can be connected to either Arduino ground or to the "lock" terminal.

Comment: ...... So lastly I decided to remove R4 and R5 and it finally worked. I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you mean by " to prevent smoke when someone presses the opposite control to what the arduino wants", would it be possible to explain in more detail? I wouldn't want to have things work now but blow up later.

Comment: if someone operates the switch in the opposite direction at the same time as the arduino sends the signal there will be a high current through one of the transistors, and then smoke as one fails

Comment: Oh I see now what you mean. Well the odds of that happening are pretty low, although the smart man said if it can happen it will happen. Thanks again!